How do upload an image from URL to Discord to be used for an embed?
I have a Discord embed for Instagram posts but the image in the embed breaks after around a week with it saying:

URL signature expired


The embed uses a link to the Instagram post's media. This link expires. I want to upload the media to Discord so it doesn't expire.
Here is the code I currently have:
import requests
from instaloader import Instaloader, LoginRequiredException, Post, Profile
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError


def create_webhook_json(post: Post):
    webhook_json = {
        "embeds": [
            {
                "title": post.owner_profile.full_name,
                "url": "https://instagram.com/p/" + post.shortcode,
                "image": {"url": post.url},
            }
        ],
        "attachments": [],
    }

    return webhook_json

def send_to_discord(post: Post):
    payload = create_webhook_json(post)

    try:
        print("Sending post sent to Discord")
        r = requests.post(discord_webhook_url, json=payload)
        r.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError as http_error:
        print("HTTP error occurred: %s", http_error)
    else:
        print("New post sent to Discord successfully.")

send_to_discord(new_post)

It just creates a JSON for a webhook and then sends that JSON webhook. Note that I'm using Instaloader.
I've tried searching online for ways to upload an image to Discord in Python but every result either is super complicated or uses a third party library which I've been trying to avoid, since I would need to refactor a lot of my code. On Discord's docs about executing a webhook it mentions about uploading files for attachments but I don't want an attachment.
I want to be able to not have to use a third-party Discord library to be able to do this.

Why do you think this is a Discord problem, and not an Instagram defense tactic?

@TimRoberts It's not an Discord problem. I'm guessing that Instagram doesn't want to want us to use their CDN for hosting images. So I'm trying to use Discord to host the images instead.

KInda kicking the can down the road here, but have you considered uploading the image to another host like Imgur and posting that link instead? Uploading to Imgur from Python is super easy (though you're limited to 10mb when uploading through their API I believe).

@thisismy-stackoverflow Not a terrible idea to use another host but I prefer to natively use Discord to host the images since it is possible to do so.

The last time I wanted to send an image in an embed from external source, I pulled the image from an external to my server in order to then send it as an attachment.
Example image fetch:
image_response = requests.get(IMAGE_URL)
    if image_response.status_code == 200:
        files = {
            'file': ('Preview.png', image_response.content, 'image/png')
       }

You can then add the files to your post request with the files= tag.
Your JSON should then look something like 'url': 'attachment://Preview.png'
However I used discord.py so I‘m not certain this works as I intend it to do.
